# SetTextColor of TextView programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a TextView in each row. I have a default color.xml with is set in the row.xml

I have different colors for different states

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!--  pressed -->
    <item 
        android:color="#ffffff"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#8b8989"/> 
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/> 

</selector>
```

This works like a charm. But when Im trying to change the color for some rows in code, this doesn't seem to work. The second_color.xml looks just the same, but with different colors. The color is changed, but for the other states (not default) nothing changes.

I change the color like this:

```
TextView tl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textlabel);
tl.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.second_color));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it!

In order to set this in code it's required to create a ColorStateList.

```
ColorStateList cl = null;
                            try {
                               XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.color.live_color);
                               cl = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), xrp);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {}

                            if(cl != null){

                                tl.setTextColor(cl);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your xml file is saved at /res/row.xml then you reference it with *R.color.row*

```
TextView tl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textlabel);
tl.setTextColor(R.color.row);
```

Comment: My row is set in row.xml where color.xml is assigned as color. However I want to change it to second_color.xml is some occasions...

Comment: I did find a solution...will post it below. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually it does not work, the right solution is `t1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.row));`